# Voronoi texture have different options

Tags: texturing, materials, node-editor

I'm following this tutorial:

[Ducky 3D - Hard Surface landscape in Blender 2.8](https://youtu.be/NOsImPUo1Vk)

But I have different options in Voronoi Texture node.
How can i get this result?

[image]

Comment: Which Blender version do you use? (The tutorial is about 2.8.) The options of the Voronoi node changed between 2.79 and 2.8 or so, the function hasn't changed much. Take a look at the output of the node and compare it to the desired result.

Answer (score 2):

The most likely reason is the blender version. Make sure you are using the same version. Ducky is using version 2.80.75. I, personally, use 2.90 and I have the same settings as Ducky has.